# Scara vs. Articulated arm robot

Tags: robotic-arm

My setup is such that my tools reside on a wall and table directly adjacent to my work bench. I wish to build an arm that will ultimately grab tools and give them to me without me having to move from my bench. I'm wondering if a scara or articulated robotic arm is better suited for this task. Payloads shouldn't exceed 5kg and distance is not fully a factor since the robot might ride a track